# Dados desatualizados em consultas Hibernate + JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Percebi um problema em minha aplicação Spring, estou implementando um serviço de mensagens internas e ao criar a exibição da quantidade de mensagens não lida percebi que o valor variava a cada atualização, sempre que uma nova mensagem chegava.
Resumindo, sempre que ocorre uma inserção ou atualização tenho uma intercalação dos desatualizados com os atualizados em cada nova consulta realizada.

> Ex: Quando exibo a quantidade de mensagens não lida o resultado fica variando da seguinte forma a cada atualização: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1...

O mesmo problema está acontecendo em todo sistema, porém em outras funcionalidades é menos perceptível.

Já tentei desativar o cache do Hibernate e dar um clear no `EntityManager`, porém o problema persiste.

Comment: @TiagoS você parece ter aprovado essa edição aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72974 porém ela é uma tentativa de adição de código de um "terceiro", que altera o propósito do autor.

Comment: Opa @diegofm, estava vendo as minhas análises e vi agora, foi mal. Pois é, foi uma falha minha mesmo, estava fazendo a análise pelo celular e eu ia clicar em rejeitar por esse motivo mesmo só que acidentalmente acabei clicando em aprovar e ai já era. Tomarei mais cuidado nas próximas vezes.